# Unitary with entries $(i,j)$ only on equidistant lattice points $\|i-j\|^2 = c^2 \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory

My research needs help in finding examples of unitary matrices $U$ which have entries
\begin{align}
U_{ij} = \begin{cases} \alpha_{ij}, \ \text{ if } \|i-j\|^2 = c^2 \\ 0 , \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{align}
where $i=(i_1,i_2,i_3),j=(j_1,j_2,j_3) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ are points with integer coordinates in a cube of size $N$ with centroid at origin, $\alpha_{ij}$ are chosen suitably to make $U$ unitary, and $c$ is a given real number. Moreover, the procedure to generate these $\alpha_{ij}$'s (for different $c$'s) should be general enough to give a basis for the lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(M)$ (Hermitian matrices of the same size as $U$ which is $M\times M$).

I'd also be okay with $U$ acting on the infinite dimensional lattice (or $c$ being an integer), if this extension somehow helps at all to answer this question. But in any case, even one nontrivial example would be very much appreciated.

I am using the [nt.number-theory](/questions/tagged/nt.number-theory) and [linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) tags, but any other potentially relevant tag would be welcome.

Comment: I'm concerned about the relative sizes of $c,N,M$. E.g., if $N$ is too small as a function of $c$, there won't be any points with $\|i-j\|^2=c^2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see, but like I mentioned, you can assume $N$ to be very large, even infinity. $M$ is of course determined by $N$ and $c$. Let's in fact assume that $c$ is the norm of a vector $p$, in which case, every $i$ has a $j$ (=$i-p$) such that $\|i-j\|^2=c^2$, so no rows or columns are zero by default.